# jQuery / Coffeescript - if conditional

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Using jQuery and coffeescript, I want to update a html element when user presses enter. My code looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $('p span').live 'keypress', (e) ->      
    if e.keyCode == 13        
      $('div.sidebar-nav ul li a.active').html $(this).attr 'value'
```

Coffeescript compiles without any errors, but the code is not working. For some reason, if I add change the code to following it works:

```
$ ->
  $('p span').live 'keypress', (e) ->      
    if e.keyCode == 13
      alert 'some string'
      $('.sidebar-nav a.active').html $(this).attr 'value'
```

I spend last few hours trying to solve this and still nothing. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Holy crap what is `$ ->` in coffeescript?

Comment: @gdoron: Like in JavaScript, `$` is just a function. `->` introduces an anonymous function. CoffeeScript also adds calling functions without parentheses. Put the pieces together, and you get `$(function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: @icktoofay. And where are the parenthesis in `.html $(this).attr 'value'`????

Comment: @gdoron: It doesn't remove the ability to use parentheses; it just makes them optional. If you're asking about whether `'value'` is another argument, it's not, because there's no comma.

Comment: @icktoofay. Thanks for this one minute tutorial, Now I'm sure I don't want to use it. YACK!

Comment: value is an argument to `attr` it's kind of like ruby syntax. fun to write, but not as elegant to read

Comment: on that note... a problem may lie in the fact that `.val` would be a more suitable function here... im not sure that attr value will return anything unless the value is explicitly added as an attribute to the html tag

Comment: Can you please show the html markup? The coffeescript looks just fine...

Comment: Why are you expecting a `<span>` to have a `value` attribute?

Comment: Please consider writing a question that *actually* deals with the minimized problem. There is nothing specific to CoffeeScript in there. Removing the syntax it can all be distilled to the selector and jQuery calls. (If you had a significantly higher reputation I would -1 for a "ought to know better" ;-)

Comment: @gdoron Do you have some kind of [fixation on bashing CoffeeScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=gdoron+coffeescript+site:stackoverflow.com)? :S

Comment: @epidemian. +1. Yes, I do... `LOL` The fact I have a good understanding of javascript and can't even read a question with basic coffeescript code makes me angry...

Comment: @gdoron Well, but it's really not that bad, even if you stick to the JS side. Take a look for example at Spine.js, which, despite its .js suffix, is written in CoffeeScript. The examples in [the documentation](http://spinejs.com/docs/models) show how it can be used both from CS or JS without any problem. Remember also that CS's motto is "it's just JS", so it's not trying to change everything you like about JS, it just tries to make coding easier (and i think it quite nails it). IDK, but i feel like going around bashing CS gives the impression that you just want to troll. I hope i'm wrong ;)

Comment: nope, [I even answered a cs question once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819668/delaying-ajax-call-in-jquery-coffeescrip/10819720#10819720). (without understanding what am I doing... `:)`) Maybe I should start learning cs, if you say it worth it, I think I should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.sidebar-nav a.active')
```

is different than...

```
$('div.sidebar-nav ul li a.active')
```

in the first case, `a.active` is a descendant of `.sidebar-nav`, and the structure under `.sidebar-nav` could be anything (list, article, spans, marquees, doesn't matter, as long as its in there somewhere). In the second, it is a great-grandchild, within a list. We'd need to see your HTML to be sure, but it looks like bad selectors...